Non-generic type to open-generic type
I need a way to map a non-generic type into a generic type for deserialization using IValueResolver or IMemberValueResolver
I found this documentation that forwards to github tests.
The problem is that there are only mappings from open-generic type to non-generic type using IValueResolver or from open-generic type to open-generic type. That way works as expected.
What I need to do is a mapping of a generic type to a non-generic type (that's working) and vise versa for deserialiation.
My types are:
public sealed class Foo<T>
{
    public T? Value { get; set; }
}

public sealed class SerializableFoo
{
    public string? TypeAQN { get; set; }

    public string? Data { get; set; }
}

I tried to create a mapping:
// Working
this.CreateMap(typeof(Foo<>), typeof(SerializableFoo), MemberList.None)
    .ForMember(nameof(SerializableFoo.TypeAQN), opt => opt.MapFrom(typeof(TypeAQNValueResolver<>)))
    .ForMember(nameof(SerializableFoo.Data), opt => opt.MapFrom(typeof(DataValueResolver<>)));

// not working
this.CreateMap(typeof(SerializableFoo), typeof(Foo<>), MemberList.None)
    .ForMember(nameof(Foo<object>.Value), opt => opt.MapFrom(typeof(SerializableToFooValueResolver<,,,>)));

private sealed class TypeAQNValueResolver<T> : IValueResolver<Foo<T>, SerializableFoo, string?>
{
    public string? Resolve(Foo<T> source, SerializableFoo destination, string? destMember, ResolutionContext context) =>
        typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName;
}

private sealed class DataValueResolver<T> : IValueResolver<Foo<T>, SerializableFoo, string?>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public string? Resolve(Foo<T> source, SerializableFoo destination, string? destMember, ResolutionContext context) =>
        source.Value?.ToString() ?? "<null>";
}

I tried to create a IValueResolve using one, two, three and even 4 generics and every time the runtime gives me this exception:

The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition.
Parameter name: instantiation

No matter how many generic paramerters I add.
How does a mapping from non-generic type to open-generic type using IValueResolver work?
DEMO dotnetfiddle
EDIT
I was able to work arround that problem by introducing an interface - but this feels wrong and only works for very specific known generics args:
public interface IFoo
{
    object? Value { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Foo<T> : IFoo
{
    public T? Value { get; set; }

    object? IFoo.Value
    {
        get => this.Value;
        set => this.Value = (T?)value;
    }
}

Mapping changes to:
this.CreateMap(typeof(SerializableFoo), typeof(IFoo), MemberList.None)
    .IncludeAllDerived()
    .ForMember(nameof(IFoo.Value), opt => opt.MapFrom(typeof(SerializableToFooValueResolver))); // Yes - generic CreateMap<,> is now possible.
this.CreateMap(typeof(SerializableFoo), typeof(Foo<>), MemberList.None)
    .IncludeBase(typeof(SerializableFoo), typeof(IFoo));

private sealed class SerializableToFooValueResolver : IValueResolver<SerializableFoo, IFoo, object?>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object? Resolve(SerializableFoo source, IFoo destination, object? destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var destinationType = destination.GetType();
        if (destinationType.IsGenericType)
        {
            var genericArgType = destinationType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            if (genericArgType == typeof(double))
            {
                return double.Parse(source.Data ?? string.Empty);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}  

This works but is definitively not the way that I want to go because that needs to handle a lot of runtime cases and feels wrong.

AutoMapper isn't a serialization library. Deserialization isn't mapping, at least as far as AutoMapper is concerned. What are you trying to deserialize and why are you involving AutoMapper at all, instead of using your serializer's customization options? AutoMapper's creator would say this isn't what AutoMapper is for, and even wrote AutoMapper's design philosophy to explain this.

As for the error itself, you have  a hard-coded mapping for the non-generic Foo<object>.Value which can never match Foo<double>.Value.  Not only is this not an open generic, you can't cast Foo<object> to Foo<double> or vice versa.

@PanagiotisKanavos Oh wow. Why does it matter that I try to use AutoMapper to create serializable instances? I only have 2 classes: one having a generic and one that doesn't have any generics. And I want to map from one to the other and vise versa. The fact that the class without generics is used to do serialization doesn't face that problem. I'm using it because we're having a persistence framework that abstracts business logic classes to serializable instances used in EntityFramework or yaml serialization. The mapping for BL <-> DTO is done by AutoMapper.

@PanagiotisKanavos you have a hard-coded mapping for the non-generic Foo.Value Where? I only used nameof for that witch results in Value without any type names. The generic used in nameof is only needed because the compiler doesn't accept nameof(Foo<>.Value). If you want replace nameof(Foo<object>.Value) by "Value" in your mind if you're feeling better this way.

Why does it matter that I try to use because you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job, one that doesn't even understand what you're trying to tell it. And Foo<object> isn't even castable to Foo<double>. Just because you used the type name as a string doesn't make the type any less closed

Think about what you're asking AutoMapper to do. Instead of telling it to map properties to properties and convert types, you're trying to tell it to change the meaning of those properties and deserialize those properties based on the type of a target property, not even the base type.

@PanagiotisKanavos Please map nameof(Foo<object>.Value) to "Value" in your mind. That`s not the problem. There is no need to cast such types! Maybe I'm using the wrong tool for that - but forget that I try to do serilaization. The problem still occurs - how to map a non-generic type to an open-generic type?

OK, what does that even mean? how to map a non-generic type to an open-generic type? That means erasing some type and ending up with an incomplete type that just can't be instantiated. Is the real question "How can I map a non-generic type to a closed generic type"? The docs you linked to say nothing about such a thing. They do say that closed generics get mapped automatically. What you want requires telling AutoMapper what property type to erase and convert to a generic type parameter. Which is something it was never built to do

because we're having a persistence framework... that suggests the framework design has issues. The abstractions that convert relational data to objects are ... ORMs like EF. But YAML isn't a database and can't even be queried, unlike any document or hierarchical databases. To abstract so different persistence mechanisms you need a domain-level multi-entity repository abstraction that produces final results directly. The DB and YAML implementations will have to be different simply because the persistence mechanisms are so different. You can't even use LINQ, which JSON/XML would allow

@PanagiotisKanavos Maybe our persistence Framework has issues - but we're able to use BL-classes that are stored by using a mapping to DTO-classes (they're different for YAML and XML and DataBases). All using the same framework and the same BL-classes. AutoMapper provides expression mapping that works perfect through our framework and uses Linq - and we can compile those expressions and filter YAML/XML <- yes in Memory. But please stop talking about our persistence framework - let's solve the problem mentioned in this question.

@PanagiotisKanavos That means erasing some type and ending up with an incomplete type that just can't be instantiated. Why? I've a mapping-definition of <SerializableFoo, Foo<>> but my mapping says var x = mapper.Map<Foo<double>>(src) <- here I'm telling AutoMapper what type to instantiate. For the type conversion a text-conversion registry is used that imports available converters that. If none is available an exception is thrown - but if any is available a T -> string -> T conversion is possible. The only thing is that I try to do that using AutoMapper using a custom value resolver.

Those tests don't use a generic in the value resolver for the destination member (it's always string`). So I'm not sure that works. Buy you can try a generic type converter instead.

@LucianBargaoanu Nope: Github-Test There is a mapping of KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> to Destination<TKey, TValue> and they're using Kvp<int, int> to Dst<string, string>. That's working - the only change is that my Kvp doesn't have any generics.

That's irrelevant. Look at the resolvers, the destination member is always string.

@LucianBargaoanu Mea culpa. I realized that while trying to strip down that unittest to my classes.

@LucianBargaoanu A generic type converter TypeConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<SerializableFoo, Foo<T>?> having a mapping declaration of CreateMap(typeof(SerializableFoo), typeof(Foo<>), MemberList.None).ConvertUsing(typeof(SerializableFooToFooTypeConverter<>)) works. But it still feels wrong because now I've to handle all properties and can't use AutoMapper do to the rest. - Nevertheless that might be the solution to my problem.

You don't need MemberList.None. You can try a PR to solve this particular case. Other than that, you can probably isolate the generic field and use a regular map for the rest.

@LucianBargaoanu Even better. I don't need a custom type converter. A mapping of CreateMap(typeof(SerializableFoo), typeof(Foo<>), MemberList.None).ForMember(nameof(Foo<object>.Value), (src, _) => Convert.ChangeType(((SerializableFoo)src).Data, Type.GetType(((SerializableFoo)src).TypeAQN))); will do the trick for me. I just didn't realize that AutoMapper creates the correct instance if typeof(Foo<>) is mapped. That helps. Thx for your hints.

I found the solution to that problem. AutoMapper creates the correct instance if a mapping using CreateMap(typeof(..), typeof(Foo<>)) is available.
After that a normal property mapping will do:
this.CreateMap(typeof(Foo<>), typeof(SerializableFoo), MemberList.None)
    .ForMember(nameof(SerializableFoo.TypeAQN), opt => opt.MapFrom(typeof(TypeAQNValueResolver<>)))
    .ForMember(nameof(SerializableFoo.Data), opt => opt.MapFrom(typeof(DataValueResolver<>)));

this.CreateMap(typeof(SerializableFoo), typeof(Foo<>), MemberList.None)
    .ForMember(nameof(Foo<object>.Value), opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Convert.ChangeType(((SerializableFoo)src).Data, Type.GetType(((SerializableFoo)src).TypeAQN))));

private sealed class TypeAQNValueResolver<T> : IValueResolver<Foo<T>, SerializableFoo, string?>
{
    public string? Resolve(Foo<T> source, SerializableFoo destination, string? destMember, ResolutionContext context) =>
        typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName;
}

private sealed class DataValueResolver<T> : IValueResolver<Foo<T>, SerializableFoo, string?>
{
    public string? Resolve(Foo<T> source, SerializableFoo destination, string? destMember, ResolutionContext context) =>
        source.Value?.ToString();
}

Having this mapping the following conversion works as expected:
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new CustomProfile()));
config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var foo = new Foo<double> { Value = 123 };
var sFoo = mapper.Map<SerializableFoo>(foo);

Console.WriteLine(sFoo.TypeAQN);
Console.WriteLine(sFoo.Data);

var unFoo = mapper.Map<Foo<int>>(sFoo);
Console.WriteLine(unFoo.Value);

Yes I know that I 'deserialized' a Foo<int> and I deserilialized a double and AutoMapper converts that double to the expected int but that's what I expected.
Having this I'm able to create a nomal property mapping - I only need to be sure that the converted value for that property matches the type or is convertible using AutoMapper.
That also works for ctor args.

That same thing would work with a generic value resolver just by using object for the destination member type. Obvious enough in hindsight :)
